# CSharpCodeProvider use custom parameter during compilation

Tags: c#, .net

I use `CSharpCodeProvider` for compile .net code from C# and generate custom DLL. But I want to set custom property in DLL like:

```
File Description
File Version
Product Name
```

It's possible?

And I have not found documentation abut the possibility to pass a XML file with all parameters for the compilation.

```
<CSharpScriptCompiler>
    <Reference>
        <Name>utils.dll</Name>
    </Reference>
    <Import>
        <Name>Expoware</Name>
    </Import>
    <Import>
        <Name>System.Text</Name>
    </Import>
</CSharpScriptCompiler>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove already existed `[assembly: AssemblyProduct()]`, `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion()]`, etc attributes from teh source and append it with your custom data.